# lazy load comments wordpress on click

Tags: php, javascript

```
 <a href="#" id="Link">Click me!</a>
    <div id="lt">The text will get loaded here</div>
  
    <script>
      $("#Link").on("click", function(){
        $("#lt").load("<?php comments_template(); ?>");
      });
    </script>
```

I asked this code to load the comments after clicking, but it does not work

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Do you have any errors in your error log or JavaScript errors in your browser console? What have you done to try and debug the issue?

Comment: Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!

Comment: you are trying to load a template file, but that is not, how its done. the template is for displaying the DATA, so you must load DATA, not template.. you need to tell wordpress, what article is currently present and make it return the related comments. there is many ways to do this. consider calling the REST api. and stop using jquery ;)

Comment: How  / / @honk31

Comment: @saeu please try to figure this out. i gave you a hint but wont come up with a complete solution. i would, if i had it, but i don't. so what i'm asking you is to try some solutions, then come back here and post your attempts, so we can help you with that.. but below is also an answer, that might work.. and please go to your previous questions and accept the right answers as a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Templates like the comments template need to be loaded on the page, as it relies on some global variables to know what post to load the comments for, so just pulling in the template with Javascript won't work like that. You'll need to create an AJAX wrapper that sets up the post data before getting the template.

Where you want your comments to go:

```
<div id="commentsTarget"><a href="#" id="loadComments">Click me!</a></div>

<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
        jQuery( '#loadComments' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ); ?>',
                data: {
                    action: 'wpse380230_load_comments',
                    postID: '<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>'
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    jQuery( '#commentsTarget' ).html( data );
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your theme `functions.php` file:

```
function wpse380230_load_comments() {
    // Check to make sure the post ID has been sent through.
    if ( isset( $_POST['postID'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['postID'] ) ) {
        // Sanitise the post ID.
        $post_id = absint( wp_unslash( $_POST['postID'] ) );
        // Set up the nessecary global variables.
        global $post, $withcomments;
        $post         = get_post( $post_id );
        $withcomments = true;
        setup_postdata( $post );
        // Time to pull in the template :).
        comments_template();
    }
    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse380230_load_comments', 'wpse380230_load_comments' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse380230_load_comments', 'wpse380230_load_comments' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much
I just have a small problem
Why not move to this (<a href = "# 1") after clicking?

Comment: @saeu I'm not sure what you mean?